# How do I rename app icons on my iPad home screen?

Tags: ios, ipad

How do I rename the apps on my home screen?

I have tried putting the app icons in edit mode ("wiggle mode") but I cannot find a way to rename them.

Comment: This is not a feature that is supported by iOS; thus, barring a jailbreak, this cannot be achieved. If you are referring to web app bookmarks, delete the current bookmark from your home screen and re-create it from within Safari, giving it a different name.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has helped me by answering my question.

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402037/how-to-customize-ios-app-icons

Answer (score 12):

iOS doesn't have that functionality.  Names of application icons are provided by the application.  You can only name folders.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't normally** rename applications on your home screen(springboard). However if your device is **jailbroken** i.e you have cydia you can use [Icon Renamer](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=36132) to change names of your applications. If you are not jailbroken wait for iOS 11 jailbreak and then rename your icons using this tweak :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to give it the name you want when you first add the icon to your home screen.  This might mean adding the link a second time, and putting your desired name in the "Add to home screen" facility.  I just click in the middle of the provided name, and delete from there until the cursor is back at the beginning of the field. Then I type the name I want for the shortcut, and delete anything else. After I have added it to the home screen I go and delete the wrongly named one - using the "jiggle" process.

Answer (score 0):

I do this. Use a website to create an item on the home screen. Then you can drag your app on top of the just created item   This will create a “group” consisting of the 2 apps. You can now rename the “group”

Comment: That wastes a click every time you want to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Shortcut - with the script option to open an App. Pick the app you want to rename. Name the shortcut what you’d like the app to appear as.  Then click on the icon in the name area and pick a color and glyph. Choose the add to Home Screen option.  Now remove the original app grime the Home Screen. Do not uninstall it of course.