# How to customize iOS app icons?

Tags: ios, applications, icon, customization, springboard

Since the release of iOS 14, people have been [sharing "aesthetic" iOS Home Screens](https://twitter.com/Kaylasfro/status/1307360943966281728).

These screenshots often feature fully custom app icons, designed and selected by the user.

How are these people changing and customizing their app icons?

[image: iOS aesthetic app icons]

Note that this is different than the [*app developer* providing alternate app icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097604/alternate-icon-in-ios-10-3), which has been possible since iOS 10.3.

Comment: The Twitter thread you linked showed that these are just shortcuts. Are you going to answer your own question or did you miss that?

Comment: @JBallin I may answer the question later if it doesn't get any good Answers, but I think this info should live on SE and not just in random twitter threads.

Comment: Related https://apple.news/AiWCThkVHT5WngZBgimywVw

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Shortcuts app to set custom icons: https://www.cultofmac.com/723677/customize-iphone-home-screen-icons-ios-14/

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link